# Permissions to trigger workflows

Tags: workflow, permissions, app-step

I have a list where I am using **item permissions** (employees have to fill up their forms and they are provided with only item edit permissions) and a main workflow (2013) working on the info they input. The **main workflow is triggering sub-workflows** (2010) to perform several operation.
When a user (with item edit permissions) has filled the form, the main workflow is started (on item change), but the sub workflows are not triggered. 
If a person with list edit (or higher) permission do it, all works fine.

I have checked one by one all sub-workflow using item-user permissions and all work fine... but they do not start if triggered by the main workflow.
 Adding ***app step*** did not help - since in that zone it is not possible to trigger workflow.
Did anybody meet with this issue? Is there some workaround?

Comment: check  How to elevate workflow permission at https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions. Unfortunately even using app or impersonation steps does not work: I realized that a **user can trigger a workflow from another one only if s/he has >edit permissions on the list/library**. Yes, with impersonation/app steps anybody is able to run a workflow but not to trigger it from another one!
But I have found a workaround that may be useful to somebody else too!

1. I've created a permission group (*ApparentEdit*) with edit permissions on the list
   and included `Everybody` there
2. At list item creation a workflow
   **revokes all permissions to this group and assign them** as I need (eg
   to *AssignedTo*)

So the *AssignedTo* person has edit on his item, can launch and trigger workflows, but still no access to other items, because each item - at creation - revokes the permissions of the *ApparentEdit* group.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an impersonation step because some workflows require the user who triggers them to have the permissions to perform the action. For instance, if you are trying to create an item in a list, the user would have to have permissions in that list to contribute.